# Map and reverseMapping without BiMap

Tags: java, dictionary

How would you go about reverse mapping without using BiMap's .inverse() function?

I was given:

```
public static Map<String, Set<String>> reverseMapping(Map<String, String> mapping)
```

I tried something like this but didn't get me anywhere.

```
      Map <String, Set<String>> remap = new HashMap<String, Set<String>>();
        for (String name : mapping.keySet()) {
            String color = mapping.get(name);
            if(remap.containsKey(color)){
            ...;
            }
            else{
                ...
            }


}
        return remap;
```

}

Comment: Can we see some code you've written to try to solve this problem?

Comment: This is problem is not too hard to solve. I agree with Louis, show us some code and we'll help if you're stuck

Comment: @Michael I added an edit with some code

Comment: You must return a Map <String, Set<String>>, not a Map<String, String>. The values of your map must be Sets of strings, not Strings, because many keys of the original map may have the same value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you're not that far away

```
public static Map<String, Set<String>> reverseMapping(Map<String, String> mapping)
{
    // slight change in the next line 
    Map <String, Set<String>> remap = new HashMap<String, Set<String>>();
    for (String name : mapping.keySet()) {
        String color = mapping.get(name);
        // Until here its ok, see comment below
    }
    // added the return
    return remap;
}
```

Now you have to check if your *remap* already contains a Set with the **key** *color*. if so add *name* to it. If not you need to create a new Set, add *name* to it, and put the new set into the *remap*

Hope this helps

Comment: I did if(remap.containsKey(color)) then remap.put(key,value) however, I don't know what to put for those values.

Comment: you first have to retrieve the Set if it already is present in the remap with Set<String> tmp = remap.get(color); then do tmp.add(name); also handle the case carefully when the Set for a color is not present yet!

Comment: you still have a little error: last line should be: remap.put(color, tmptwo);

Comment: you still have a little error: last line should be: remap.put(color, tmptwo);